# How add class youtube and type/html to oembed code?

Tags: youtube, oembed, video-player

How can i add :

```
class="youtube-player" type="text/html"
```

to iframe like :

```
 function Oembed_youtube_no_title($html,$url,$args){
    $url_string = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
    parse_str($url_string, $id);
    if (isset($id['v'])) {
        return '<iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' .$id['v'].'?vq=large&autohide=1&autoplay=1&fs=1&hl=fr&rel=0&loop=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
    }
    return $html;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can try this:

```
add_filter( 'embed_oembed_html', 'custom_youtube_oembed' );
function custom_youtube_oembed( $code ){
    if( stripos( $code, 'youtube.com' ) !== FALSE && stripos( $code, 'iframe' ) !== FALSE )
        $code = str_replace( '<iframe', '<iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" ', $code );

    return $code;
}
```

to target the YouTube oembed HTML output.

When I embed this YouTube link (Kraftwerk) into the post content

```
http://youtu.be/VXa9tXcMhXQ
```

I get this HTML output:

```
<iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html"  
        width="625" height="469" 
        src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/VXa9tXcMhXQ?feature=oembed" 
        frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

with the above filter.

Comment: Is there no way to check that the oEmbed is a YouTube video other than searching the HTML code (or the second parameter URL, not shown above) for the string `youtube.com`? Is there some type or other property that can be accessed?

Comment: I haven't looked into this for a while. I skimmed now through the code and noticed that there is the `wp_embed_handler_youtube` filter available, but it looks like it could only work on the  `#https?://(www.)?youtube\.com/(?:v|embed)/([^/]+)#i` types of urls. There's also a discussion [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/30660) about it. Why do you need another approach? Before or after the oembed caching? Maybe this would be better serverd as a new question? @Jamil

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to *birgire's* solution above, if you want to also get rid of the width and height so that you can fully control the css, adding this worked for me:

```
 $code = str_replace( 'width="640"', '', $code );
 $code = str_replace( 'height="360"', '', $code );
```

Not sure this won't cause other problems, but tested and seems to work.